# LWJGL Mutlithreading Loading

Tags: java, textures, lwjgl

I am trying to create a loading thread with my objs and textures without using any opengl functions. I figured out how to do it with my objs but the textures will be black after loading. I am doing all of my reading of the file in the loading threads. After I am done with the loading threads I will resume the creation of the game so everything will be already loaded once the game starts.

This is my TextureLoaderThread class

```
package com.widowmc.threads;

import java.util.HashMap;

import com.widowmc.graphics.textures.TextureData;

public class TextureLoaderThread extends Thread {

    private String[] TERRAINIMGS = {"blendMap", "grassFlowers", "grassy2", "mud", "path"};
    private String[] IMGS = {"fern", "player", "tree"};

    private HashMap<String, TextureData> textureDatas = new HashMap<String, TextureData>();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            for(String str : TERRAINIMGS) {
                textureDatas.put(str, new TextureData("terrain", str));
                System.out.println("Terrain Image - " + str);
            } 
            for(String str : IMGS) {
                textureDatas.put(str, new TextureData(str));
                System.out.println("Image - " + str);
            } 
            notify();
        }
    }

    public TextureData getTextureData(String name) {
        return textureDatas.get(name);
    }

}
```

This is my TextureData class

```
package com.widowmc.graphics.textures;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import com.widowmc.utils.MyFile;

public class TextureData {

    public int[] data;
    public int width, height;

    public TextureData(String name) {
        int[] pixels = null;
        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new MyFile("res/" + name + ".png").getInputStream());
            width = image.getWidth();
            height = image.getHeight();
            pixels = new int[width * height];
            image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, pixels, 0, width);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        data = new int[width * height];
        for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++) {
            int a = (pixels[i] & 0xff000000) >> 24;
            int r = (pixels[i] & 0xff0000) >> 16;
            int g = (pixels[i] & 0xff00) >> 8;
            int b = (pixels[i] & 0xff);

            data[i] = a << 24 | b << 16 | g << 8 | r;
        }
    }

    public TextureData(String dir, String name) {
        int[] pixels = null;
        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new MyFile("res/" + dir + "/" + name + ".png").getInputStream());
            width = image.getWidth();
            height = image.getHeight();
            pixels = new int[width * height];
            image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, pixels, 0, width);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        data = new int[width * height];
        for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++) {
            int a = (pixels[i] & 0xff000000) >> 24;
            int r = (pixels[i] & 0xff0000) >> 16;
            int g = (pixels[i] & 0xff00) >> 8;
            int b = (pixels[i] & 0xff);

            data[i] = a << 24 | b << 16 | g << 8 | r;
        }
    }

    public int[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about your question here so that we can help you solve your problem?

Comment: Are that I want to do is to load the textures from a different thread without sharing the context. So I made classes to handle all none opengl loading and then use those classes for the different threads.